# Is there .all() or .any() equivalent in python Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to find a similar operation to `.any()`, `.all()` methods that will work on a tensor. Here is a scenario:

```
a = tf.Variable([True, False, True], dtype=tf.bool)

# this is how I do it right now
has_true = a.reduce_sum(tf.cast(a, tf.float32)) 
# this is what I'm looking for
has_true = a.any()
```

Currently converting my boolean tensor into `int` using `reduce_sum` to see if there are any truths in it. Is there a cleaner way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are [`tf.reduce_any`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_any) and [`tf.reduce_all`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_all) methods:

```
sess = tf.Session()

a = tf.Variable([True, False, True], dtype=tf.bool)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

sess.run(tf.reduce_any(a))
# True
sess.run(tf.reduce_all(a))
# False
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!